# Which dll has 'BusyIndicator' for silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, busyindicator

I have installed Nov '09 silverlight 3 toolkit. Referenced System.Windows.Control from C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v3.0 Libraries\Client\System.Windows.Controls.dll

but when I compile my code I am getting
"Error 6 The type or namespace name 'BusyIndicator' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows.Controls' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

I opened the dll in object browser and I could not find the busyindicator either. Could some one please tell me which dll has the Busy Indicator?

I found the following link regarding the same issue but did not say which dll has this class.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the *System.Windows.Controls.**Toolkit*** assembly.

[Direkt link to the source code.](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/35261#777793)

Generally, I'd strongly recommend to switch to 4.0 though.

Comment: I personally have switched to 4.0.  Blend is content with my project, but Visual Studio says it doesn't exist.  What is the Silverlight 4 toolkit assembly please?  Is it the same?

Comment: Why not 5? Just download and install the right version from http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases